# Laravel 8 Queue Errors Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::unserialize(string $data): void must be compatible with Serializable::unserialize($serialized)

Tags: laravel, serialization, queue, laravel-8

I have some notifications (that get sent out to SendGrid) and I am using table queues.

I build my notification as below

```
$data = [
    'email_message' => $message,
    'subject' => $request->subject,
    'email' => $request->email
];

$user->notify(new EmailGeneralNotification($data));
```

My Notification looks like this;

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use NotificationChannels\SendGrid\SendGridChannel;
use NotificationChannels\SendGrid\SendGridMessage;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
// use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use App\Models\NotificationTemplate;

class EmailGeneralNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{

    use Queueable;
    // use SerializesModels;

    protected $data;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }


    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            SendGridChannel::class,
        ];
    }
    

    public function toSendGrid($notifiable)
    {
        $reference = 'internal_general_email';
        $template = NotificationTemplate::where('reference',$reference)->latest('updated_at')->first();

        if(!$template)
        {
            dd("No template was found for " . $reference);
        }

        return (new SendGridMessage($template->template_id))
            /**
             * optionally set the from address.
             * by default this comes from config/mail.from
             * ->from('no-reply@test.com', 'App name')
             */
            /**
             * optionally set the recipient.
             * by default it's $notifiable->email:
             * ->to('hello@example.com', 'Mr. Smith')
             */
            ->payload([
                "subject" => (array_key_exists('subject', $this->data)) ? $this->data['subject'] : '',
                "email_message" => (array_key_exists('email_message', $this->data)) ? $this->data['email_message'] : '',
            ]);
    }
}
```

This gets sent via a SendGrid notification type.

The funny this is that when I remove the `implements ShouldQueue` and `use Queueable` and run my function everything works fine.

When I enable the queue I get the below;

```
[2022-10-30 08:34:08] local.ERROR: Declaration of Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::unserialize(string $data): void must be compatible with Serializable::unserialize($serialized) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Declaration of Ramsey\\Uuid\\Uuid::unserialize(string $data): void must be compatible with Serializable::unserialize($serialized) at /var/www/html/vendor/ramsey/uuid/src/Uuid.php:307)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

I have updated php to v8 and got Laravel to 8.83.25 but still no joy

Comment: It looks like any queued jobs have the same issue, so not just limited to these sendgrid email notifications either

Comment: Has there been any progress? or a solution

Comment: I am seeing this error too and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

There ended up being an incompatibility in my project. I upgraded to Laravel 9 and it's working fine.